Ubuntu 24.04 WSL2 distribution failed to install on Windows 10
Had a working copy of default Ubuntu distribution on my Windows 10 Enterprise work laptop. I seemed to have messed up when trying to build custom kernel to enable nested-virtualization support, which I later learnt is not at all supported on WSL2 on Windows 10 (but only on Windows 11) due to some missing APIs. This resulted in an error saying that 'customer kernel specified in .wslconfig' was not found. I removed (unregistered) the default Ubuntu installation and tried to reinstall Ubuntu-24.04 distribution on this system, which ended up in this error:
PS C:\Users\bdutta> wsl.exe --install Ubuntu-24.04
Installing: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS has been installed.
Launching Ubuntu 24.04 LTS...
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80040307
Error: 0x80040307 (null)
Press any key to continue...

What might be the issue here ? How to resolve this ?

Shortly after posting this question, I came across this link (https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8561) where I found the answer. All I had to do was to delete the .wslconfig file which had the troublesome custom kernel. Once that was removed, installation went through.

You can post that as answer. Make sure to also quote the relevant part.

Found the solution in this link and the solution really was to delete the .wslconfig file that referenced the troublesome custom kernel. One the .wslconfig file is removed from the home directory of the user, the installation went through fine.
